# How to iterate using iterator over API object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-objects, fetch-api

I want to iterate over a JSON object(array) through JavaScript iterator. I am not able to store the data fetched from the iterator function in a variable so that I can use the variable for DOM manipulation.

```
next.addEventListener('click',nextCV);
function nextCV(){
   const a =getCV().then(data=> 
    data.next().value)
    

}

function getCV(){
    
    
     return fetch(url).then(response=>{return response.json()
    }).then(data=>{
        
       
        return iteratorCV(data.results)
    })
    
}

function iteratorCV(data){
    console.log('inside iterator')
    let nextindex=0;
    return {
        next: function(){
            return nextindex<data.length ? {value: data[nextindex++], done:false} : {done:true};
        }
    };
}
```

Here I want to get the next array data stored to variable 'a' whenever a click event occurs.
Please help.

P.S. I am still in the process of learning JavaScript.

Comment: Do you want to learn iterator protocol or just want this to work? Because it will be easier if you use generators. Also arrays are also iterators so your iteratorCV is pointless.

Comment: Just use `array[Symbol.iterator]()` to get the iterator from `data.results` you don't need iteratorCV function.

Comment: Hi jcubic, I am using iterator as for every click i want to iterate to the next array element.Does arrays have implicit iterate function?If so, can please elaborate or share any useful link.

Comment: As I've commented `array[Symbol.iterator]()` is explicit iterate function that is the same as output of iteratorCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `getCV()` which does repeat the request and create a new iterator every time you click the element. It sounds like what you actually want to do is

```
const iteratorPromise = getCV();
iteratorPromise.catch(console.error);
next.addEventListener('click', function nextCV(e) {
  iteratorPromise.then(iterator => {
    const a = iterator.next().value;
    console.log(a); // or DOM manipulation
  });
});
```

or

```
getCV().then(iterator => {
  next.addEventListener('click', function nextCV(e) {
    const a = iterator.next().value
    console.log(a); // or DOM manipulation
  });
}).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Hi Bergi, Thank you so much for replying and pointing out the repeating request part.But now I am getting 'undefined' if i am trying to const iteratorPromise = getCV(); and console.log(iteratorPromise).So further hitting click is giving me another error.cv.js:15 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
    at HTMLButtonElement.nextCV (cv.js:15)

Comment: Hm, that's weird, the `getCV()` function in your question does `return` a promise?

Comment: Yes it is returning a promise.Now i am getting this error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'next')
    at HTMLButtonElement.nextCV (cv.js:27)
 
`getCV().then(iterator => {
    next.addEventListener('click', function nextCV(e) {
        
      const a = iterator.next().value
      console.log(a); // or DOM manipulation
    });
  })`
  
 the iterator variable is getting undefined assigned. :(

Comment: Sounds like the promise doesn't fulfill with the iterator as its result. Your `getCV` function still does `return iteratorCV(data.results)` from the promise chain, right?

Comment: Sorry @Bergin i was doing a silly mistake in the code the array data was actually data.results. But i was passing the it as an object..my input looks like.. {"results":[{"gender":"female","name":{"title":"Miss",.................}... I have made the changes accordingly now your code is working fine.Thanks for your time .Really appreciate

Comment: I ll make sure from next time i will include input as well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to simulate the `fetch` Promise and I think this is what you're looking for? Ofcourse there can be optimizations like avoid making the same API call and just return the `cached` result depending on the usecase.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click',nextCV);
async function nextCV(){
   let it = await getCV();
   let result = it.next();
   const a = [];
   while(!result.done) {
    a.push(result.value)
    result = it.next();
   }
 // Result stores in 'a'. Do DOM manipulation from here
  console.log('final result', a);
   
   
}

function getCV(){
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(iteratorCV([1,2,3,4,5]))
      }, 1000)
    })
}

function iteratorCV(data){
    console.log('inside iterator')
    let nextindex=0;
    return {
        next: function(){
            return nextindex<data.length ? {value: data[nextindex++], done:false} : {done:true};
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<button> Click </button>
```

Comment: Hi Kanishk, Thanks for your reply. Can you please help me that how can i use fetch api in the getCV() and is it necessary to use setTimeout()?

Comment: @Astro just replace the code in `getCV` from my snippet to your `fetch` code. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I guess we cannot use Promise keyword with fetch() .Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: I was giving wrong input(object instead of an array) to data parameter in interatorCV function.Thanks for this approach.I have not much concepts about async await.I will try and let you know if this approach works too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for their valuable time.Here is how i got my final out.Hope this helps someone in future.

```
const url="https://.......";

//adding button for the iteration
const next = document.getElementById('next');


//for Dom manipulation
let image=document.getElementById('image');
let profile=document.getElementById('profile');



getCV().then(iterator => {
    next.addEventListener('click', function nextCV(e) {
        
       const a = iterator.next().value
       console.log(a);
       //now you can use the variable for DOM manipulation 
       image.innerHTML=       });
  })

//get api

function getCV(){
    
    
         return fetch(url).then(response=>{ 
           return response.json()
    }).then(data=>{
        
        
         console.log(data.results)
         return iteratorCV(data.results);
         
    })
    
}


//Iterating over the FETCHED DATA one by one data


function iteratorCV(data){
    console.log('inside iterator')
    // console.log(data)
    let nextindex=0;
    return {
        next: function(){
            return nextindex<data.length ? {value: data[nextindex++], done:false} : {done:true};
        }
    };
}
```